# JSF specifying it as parameter in the URL JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF page with a form which contains fields "company". I am trying to pre-populate the company fields with the URL.
So, once the following link is clicked

> localhost/accounts/index.jsf?company=test

users should see the form with company field filled with value "test".

Here is my JSF file

```
<p><h:inputText id="company" name="company" value="#{Bean.company}" required="true"
                                                        requiredMessage="Please enter your company" /></p>
```

I have tried to use f:viewParam by followed this tutorial (8. page parameters), but still could not get it working.
http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-do-10-common-tasks-jsf-20

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Post the code (JSF, Java, etc) that gives you problems.

Comment: why dont you set the value of company in Bean constructor itself as "test" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To capture param value, you should use `<f:metadata>`

```
 <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="company" value="#{Bean.company}" />
</f:metadata>

<p>
<h:inputText id="company" name="company"
           value="#{Bean.company}" required="true"
 requiredMessage="Please enter your company" />
</p>
```